Website error saying "object can not be found" but both paths are the same
I'm currently building a website and I have come across what should be an easy fix, but I cannot seem to pinpoint the error. When I navigate to certain aspects of my page, and I click on "register", it takes me the page I have set up for it. But from other aspects of my page (and I click the same exact button), it does not work and takes me to the "object can not be found" aspect of my website. Any ideas or even ways to test where the error is coming from? This all stems from the "accountMenu.js" file I have.
This is the same exact JS code on each page (about.html (works here) and index.html):
var accountMenuLoggedOut = document.createElement('div');
            accountMenuLoggedOut.id = 'accountMenuLoggedOut';
            accountMenuLoggedOut.className = 'account-menu';
            accountMenuLoggedOut.style.display = 'none';
            accountMenuLoggedOut.innerHTML = `
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a></li>
                </ul>
            `;

This is my accountMenu.js file:
// Check login status
function isLoggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === 'true';
}

// Check admin status
function isAdmin() {
    return localStorage.getItem('isAdmin') === 'true';
}

// Inject the dropdown menus into the page
function injectAccountMenus() {
    console.log("Injecting account menus");

    var accountMenuLoggedIn = document.createElement('div');
    accountMenuLoggedIn.id = 'accountMenuLoggedIn';
    accountMenuLoggedIn.className = 'account-menu';
    accountMenuLoggedIn.style.display = 'none';
    accountMenuLoggedIn.innerHTML = `
        <ul>
            <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
            ${!isAdmin() ? '<li><a href="reservationStatus.html">Status</a></li>' : ''}
            ${isAdmin() ? '<li><a href="adminRequests.html">Requests</a></li>' : ''}
            <li><a href="#" id="logoutButton">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    `;
    console.log("Created logged-in menu", accountMenuLoggedIn);

    var accountMenuLoggedOut = document.createElement('div');
    accountMenuLoggedOut.id = 'accountMenuLoggedOut';
    accountMenuLoggedOut.className = 'account-menu';
    accountMenuLoggedOut.style.display = 'none';
    accountMenuLoggedOut.innerHTML = `
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../pages/login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="../pages/register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a></li>
        </ul>
    `;
    console.log("Created logged-out menu", accountMenuLoggedOut);

    document.body.appendChild(accountMenuLoggedIn);
    document.body.appendChild(accountMenuLoggedOut);

    updateAccountButton();
}

// Update account button
function updateAccountButton() {
    console.log("Updating account button");

    var accountButton = document.getElementById('accountButton');
    var accountMenuLoggedIn = document.getElementById('accountMenuLoggedIn');
    var accountMenuLoggedOut = document.getElementById('accountMenuLoggedOut');

    if (!accountButton) {
        console.error("Account button not found!");
        return;
    }

    // Clear previous event listeners
    var newAccountButton = accountButton.cloneNode(true);
    accountButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newAccountButton, accountButton);
    accountButton = newAccountButton;

    console.log("Cleared previous event listeners from account button");

    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        console.log("User is logged in");
        accountButton.innerText = 'Account';
        accountButton.href = '#';
        accountButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            toggleAccountMenu(accountMenuLoggedIn);
        });

        const logoutButton = document.getElementById('logoutButton');
        if (logoutButton) {
            logoutButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Logging out");
                localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
                localStorage.removeItem('isAdmin');
                window.location.reload();
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Logout button not found!");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("User is not logged in");
        accountButton.innerText = 'Account';
        accountButton.href = '#';
        accountButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            toggleAccountMenu(accountMenuLoggedOut);
        });
    }
}

// Toggle account menu
function toggleAccountMenu(menu) {
    console.log("Toggling account menu", menu);

    var menus = document.querySelectorAll('.account-menu');
    menus.forEach(function(m) {
        if (m !== menu) {
            m.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    menu.style.display = (menu.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';

    // Close the menu if clicked outside
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!menu.contains(event.target) && event.target.id !== 'accountButton') {
            menu.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, { once: true });
}

function logoutUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
    localStorage.removeItem('isAdmin');
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
}

// Call the function to inject the menus after the DOM is fully loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', injectAccountMenus);


Can you share the full and exact error message? Are the URLs you request the same, or different? Is this a PHP problem or a JS problem?

You do realize, that anyone visiting on the page can set whatever keys and values to localStorage, and then ex. being recognized as admin by your code?

Are those pages(?) from where it does not work, under a different path perhaps? What the relative URL register.php resolves to, of course depends on the URL of the currently viewed document.

ways to test...start with the developer tools in your browser, maybe. If you mean you're getting a 404 error it probably means the  URL it was told to navigate to is simply wrong, though.
